# GitHub Pages Jekyll hosted blog doesn't pick up remote_theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I've just installed a Jekyll blog and I've tested it locally with a `remote_theme` and locally, it works fine. However when it's being deployed to GH page I see that the theme is `minima` (the default one).

In my `_config.yml`:

```
remote_theme: benbalter/retlab
plugins:
  - jekyll-remote-theme
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-include-cache
```

In my `Gemfile`:

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "github-pages"
  gem "jekyll-feed"
  gem "jekyll-include-cache"
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
  gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
end

gem "jekyll-remote-theme"
```

I have also tried to change the `url` and `baseUrl` in `_config.yml` and the result is exactly the same. I also tried to use other themes such as `remote_theme: "mmistakes/minimal-mistakes@4.24.0"` and the result is exactly the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have local files (layouts etc) within the project using that `remote_theme` that are overriding the theme's?